# SharePoint Javascript object not filled correct?

Tags: javascript, ajax, sharepoint-2013, asynchronous

I use following code to color the countries of a worldmap. There are two problems which, I think have to do with the fact that I set asynch to FALSE. The first problem is the fact that the countries all get the same color even they are set in Dataset to "NEW" or "OLD".
Second problem is the data.event for the mouseover function always returns the same value, namely the first item in the list.

```
<script src="http://dwrd.mindef.nl/sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dwrd.mindef.nl/sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://dwrd.mindef.nl/sites/SWR000744/SiteAssets/Scripts/datamaps.world.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {

function getDaysInMonth(m, y) {
    return m===2 ? y & 3 || !(y%25) && y & 15 ? 28 : 29 : 30 + (m+(m>>3)&1);
}

function stringToDate(_date,_format,_delimiter)
{
        var formatLowerCase=_format.toLowerCase();
        var formatItems=formatLowerCase.split(_delimiter);
        var dateItems=_date.split(_delimiter);
        var monthIndex=formatItems.indexOf("mm");
        var dayIndex=formatItems.indexOf("dd");
        var yearIndex=formatItems.indexOf("yyyy");
        var month=parseInt(dateItems[monthIndex]);
        month-=1;
        var formatedDate = new Date(dateItems[yearIndex],month,dateItems[dayIndex]);
        return formatedDate;
}

var today = new Date();

var numberOfDaysLastMonth = getDaysInMonth(today.getMonth(), today.getFullYear());    //number of days last month
var numberOfDaysThisMonth = getDaysInMonth(today.getMonth()+1, today.getFullYear());  //number of days this month
    if (numberOfDaysLastMonth < today.getDate()) {
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate  = startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(startDate.getMonth()-1)+"-"+startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 1);  // returns laatste 2 maanden
} else {
        var startDate = new Date();
        startDate  = startDate.getFullYear()+"-"+(startDate.getMonth()-1)+"-"+startDate.getDate();  // returns de vorige maand
};

getDaysInMonth(today.getMonth()+1, today.getFullYear())


var urlForAllItems = "/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('OIE Alerts')/Items?" +  "$select=Title,Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event,Causal_x0020_agent,Country0/Title,Country0/Column2&$expand=Country0&" + "$filter=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event gt '"+startDate+"'&$orderby=Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event desc";


var items = [];        // is een array
var countryCode = "";
var dataset = {};      // is een object
var countryData = {};
var someDate = new Date();
startDate = stringToDate(startDate,"yyyy-MM-dd","-");
var inbetweenDate = new Date();
inbetweenDate = inbetweenDate.setDate(today.getDate()-30);

getItems(urlForAllItems);

function getItems(url) {
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + url,
    type: "GET",
    async:false,
headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    },
    success: function (data) {
    var items = data.d.results;
         countryData.event = "";
         for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
            someDate = new Date(items[i].Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event);
                countryCode = items[i].Country0.Column2; 
            if (someDate < inbetweenDate) {
            //countryData.fillKey = 'OLD';
            //dataset[countryCode] = countryData;
            } else {
            countryData.event = items[i].Causal_x0020_agent;
                countryData.fillKey = 'NEW';
            dataset[countryCode] = countryData;
            }


        }

    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));
    }
});
}

var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    geographyConfig: {
    popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
              if (typeof data != 'null' && data) {
            return '<div class="hoverinfo">' + geo.properties.name + ' OIE Alert: ' +  data.event + '</div>'
       } },

    hideAntarctica: true,
            highlightFillColor: false,
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: false,
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 0.5
            },
        fills: {
        NEW: '#FF0000',
        OLD: '#FF7F7F',
    defaultFill: '#FFFED9' // Any hex, color name or rgb/rgba value
        },
    data: dataset
        });

    //map.svg.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw));

// zoom in and out functionality
function redraw() {
map.svg.selectAll("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}

});

</script>
<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

Does anyone know what is causing this problem?
Could it be the object 'dataset' isn't filled correct?

Regards
Marco

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>DataMaps</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A jQuery plugin for geographical map data visualizations using d3.js, SVG.">
    <meta name="google-site-verification" content="zLCvhju2XBR2bPX9KvLIcnYTcsyjWuEeBda0JfQz7ww" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    </head>
<body class="tk-source-sans-pro">
<script src="d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="topojson.min.js"></script>
<script src="datamaps.world.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="position: relative; width: 1000px; height: 600px;"></div>
<script>

var dataset = {};
var countryData = {};
var iso = "";

iso = 'RUS';
countryData.fillKey = 'OLD';
countryData.agent = "H5N1";
dataset[iso] = { fillKey: countryData.fillKey, agent: countryData.agent };
iso = 'CAN';
countryData.fillKey = 'NEW';
countryData.agent = "H5N8";
dataset[iso] = { fillKey: countryData.fillKey, agent: countryData.agent  };
iso = 'AUS';
countryData.fillKey = "OLD";
countryData.agent = "Pokken";
dataset[iso] = { fillKey: countryData.fillKey, agent: countryData.agent  };
iso = 'BRA';
countryData.fillKey = 'NEW';
countryData.agent = "Vogelgriep";
dataset[iso] = { fillKey: countryData.fillKey, agent: countryData.agent  };
console.log(dataset);

var map = new Datamap({
    element: document.getElementById('container'),
    geographyConfig: {
            popupTemplate: function(geo, data) {
            if (!data) { return ; }
            return '<div class="hoverinfo"><strong>' + geo.properties.name + '</strong><br>OIE Alert: ' +  data.agent + '</div>'
            console.log(data.agent);
            },
            hideAntarctica: true,
            highlightFillColor: false,
            popupOnHover: true,
            highlightOnHover: false,
            borderColor: '#000000',
            borderWidth: 0.5
            },
    fills: {
            'NEW': '#FF0000',
            'OLD': '#FFCCCC',
            defaultFill: '#FFFED9' // Any hex, color name or rgb/rgba value
        },
    data: dataset

        });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```